# Converting an array of chars to std::string in order to pass into std::bitset seg fault

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion, bitset

before you down vote this please read carefully, it does get interesting. Basically I want to convert a type `char` array into an `std::string` in order to use `std::bitset` operations but when I try to create the `bitset` object at runtime I get this error.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>   what():  bitset::_M_copy_from_ptr Aborted (core dumped)

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    char BYTE_4[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 0};

    std::string str_BYTE_4 = std::string(BYTE_4);

    std::bitset<32> str_BYTE_4_bit( str_BYTE_4);//crash here
    std::cout<<"str_BYTE_4_bit. "<<str_BYTE_4_bit<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried some other types of conversion with `std::stringstream` and pointers of both `char` and `std::string` and no matter what I pass into that `std::bitset` constructor I get the same error?

These are just snippets I commented out and removed from the above code, to show what I tried.

```
//char* BYTE_4 = new char[4];
    //std::stringstream SS;

    //std::string str_BYTE_4 = "0101";
    //SS << BYTE_4;
        //str_BYTE_4 = SS.str();
    //for(int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        //    str_BYTE_4 += BYTE_4[index];

    //std::string *str_BYTE_4 = new std::string[4];
    //for( int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        //    BYTE_4[index] = rand()%255;
```

Comment: The string should contain characters `'0'` and `'1'`, not the integers `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
char BYTE_4[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 0};
std::string str_BYTE_4 = std::string(BYTE_4);
```

What you need is a string of digits, but you are storing raw bytes `1` and `0` (not ASCII "1" and "0").  Fix it like this:

```
char BYTE_4[4] = { '1', '0', '0', '0'};
std::string str_BYTE_4 = std::string(BYTE_4, sizeof(BYTE_4));
```

Since there is no null terminator, you must tell the `std::string` constructor where to stop (by passing `4` as the second argument).

An even easier way would be:

```
std::string str_BYTE_4 = "1000";
```

As for the `invalid_argument` exception you got, you will see if you read the documentation for `bitset` that it means you passed a string which contained a character that was neither `'0'` nor `'1'` (those being ASCII characters, whose raw integer values are 48 and 49).

Comment: Yup tried it, but why though? If I initialize a char to zero it's zero why not 1?

Comment: @pandoragami: I think you have failed to understand the difference between the character `'0'` and the number `0`.  http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: so I can't use 'start of heading' or NULL as a value, basically but I should be able to use 48 or 49?

Comment: The documentation is clear: the string can only contain the ASCII characters `'0'` and `'1'`.  SOH is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::string` constructed from

```
char BYTE_4[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 0};
```

is no different than the the `std::string` constructed from

```
char BYTE_4[4] = { 1, '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

You only have the `char` represented by the integer value `1` in the `std:string`. That is the source of the problem.

In order to be able to construct a `std::bitset` from a `std::string`, you need the `std::string` to contain only the characters `'1'` or `'0'`. Hence you need to use the charactes `'1'` and `'0'`, not the integer values `1` and `0`.

You can use:

```
char BYTE_4[] = {'1', '0', '0', '0', '\0'};
std::string str_BYTE_4 = std::string(BYTE_4);
```

or

```
char BYTE_4[4] = {'1', '0', '0', '0'};
std::string str_BYTE_4 = std::string(BYTE_4, 4);
```

in order to be able to construct a `std::bitset` from the `std::string`.

**For what it's worth:**

```
std::bitset<32> str_BYTE_4_bit(std::string());
```

creates a `bitset` whose value consists of 32 zero bits.

```
std::bitset<32> str_BYTE_4_bit(std::string("1000"));
```

creates a `bitset` whose value consists of 28 leading bits that are zero and the last 4 bits are 1000.